# Disable Multi-Tenancy from ABP.io

Tags: asp.net, abp

We have recently started to build our project on top of ABP.io. In our project, we don't have requirement for multi-tenancy. so we want to completely remove that from project.

I tried to find the solution from available documents of ABP.io. However I couldn't found any related document to do so.

Is it possible to remove multi-tenancy from ABP.io project? If yes what are the steps to do that?

Answer (score 3):

I think you can switch MultiTenancyoff from here in **Domain.Shared project**

```
public static class MultiTenancyConsts
{
    /* Enable/disable multi-tenancy easily in a single point.
     * If you will never need to multi-tenancy, you can remove
     * related modules and code parts, including this file.
     */
    public const bool IsEnabled = false;
}
```

Comment: Yeah it does disable Tenancy. But still it's API and configuration exists in project and can visible in Swagger. I want to completely remove all reference of Multi Tenancy from project.Do you know the way to do that?

Answer (score 1):

In relation to the API still functioning, you should be able to override any controllers or appservices.

[ABP guide to override](https://docs.abp.io/en/abp/4.4/Customizing-Application-Modules-Overriding-Services)

This will not entirely remove the endpoints, but you can shut them down completetely, leaving them with no functionality, just by leaving them empty.

```
using Volo.Abp.Identity;

[RemoteService(true, Name = "AbpIdentity")]
[Route("api/identity/organization-units", Order = 1)]
[ControllerName("OrganizationUnit")]
[ExposeServices(typeof(OrganizationUnitController),typeof(IAppOrganizationUnitAppService))]
[Area("identity")]

public class AppOrganizationUnitController : OrganizationUnitController, IAppOrganizationUnitAppService, IOrganizationUnitAppService
{

     public override Task AddMembersAsync(Guid id, OrganizationUnitUserInput input){
     {

}
```

[This might also do it](https://support.abp.io/QA/Questions/255/We-don%27t-want-to-use-the-Organization-Unit-functionality-and-want-to-remove-it-from-the-UIAPI#answer-e417f04d-4fe3-c8d1-e36a-39f5f89805ef) - ABP issue answer